# Selenium / Python : Using Keyboard Input

Tags: python, selenium

Issue: Unable to select an element and then execute a keyboard input of the down arrow.

Situation: I am opening a page, making a few selections, and after each selection is executed by the .click() event, I want to simulate a keyboard input of the down arrow. I get an exception error, and have tried different ways, with no success.

Error: `WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: cannot focus element\n  (Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.69)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.4 x86_64)'`

```
def test_00_validation_test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.set_window_position(0,0)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id("open").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("screen_name").send_keys("user")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pwd")
        driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("card5").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("make_picks").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("team3").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("team3").send_keys("\25")
        driver.find_element_by_id("team2").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("team2").send_keys("\25")
        driver.find_element_by_id("submit_picks").click()
        self.assertEqual("Picks Saved", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch_to_alert()
    Switches focus to an alert on the page.
```

[doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)

you have to focus on `open_popup` in order to send keys in that popup

Comment: I see where you thought this and changed that wording. Good on manipulating pop ups, thanks. I am trying to input the down arrow to simulate the user scrolling the page down using the Down Arrow key.

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: if theres no popup it maybe related to this http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=35. is it a <p> element?

Comment: I think I am going about this wrong. I just want to scroll down the page about 1/2 way. Using the down arrow seemed like a simple solution.

Comment: hm i think selenium believes you are trying to type in an element.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. Using `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")`